# Recover Data Using Synology NAS

Tags: hard-drive, raid, data-recovery, nas, synology

I bought a Synology DS415play around 2 years ago, and plugged 3x 4TB hard drives into it and set them up as a Synology Hybrid RAID. I've been using it to store my media on it and haven't touched the setup since.

I've just found an old PC of mine and wanted to see if there's anything worthwhile on my old PC drive. I've plugged the drive into the fourth slot on my Synology, and it's recognising the drive but I'm not sure how to access the data on the drive.

The HDD/SSD window looks like this:

[image]

While the Volume window looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to access the data on this drive using my Synology?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Similar, almost duplicate question: https://superuser.com/questions/721412/accessing-an-old-populated-hard-drive-with-a-nas/804690#804690

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing an old, populated hard drive with a NAS?](https://superuser.com/questions/721412/accessing-an-old-populated-hard-drive-with-a-nas)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR guessing this can't be done. I'd suggest a USB hard drive adapter, otherwise if the old PC is working boot it normally, not working boot it with a CD or USB live linux system.

Disk 4 (old PC HDD you inserted I'm guessing) shows Not Initialized meaning its likely not mounted so is not browsable. When you install a drive into the NAS, they're assuming it's going to be part of a RAID or unique file system to that NAS. They usually don't support an existing file system & files on a HDD nor do they likely allow you to share two different mounted files systems at once because its not a normal desire